# Drag Drop and Reorder elements in ListView

Tags: android-listview, drag-and-drop

I'm following [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) library to add drag - drop functionality my listview. Everything is fine when moving first item to second place. But when I move the listview first element to third place app crashes. In order to explain my situation I've added image. All I think it is caused at Swap items line but i think my code right. When I try to replace first item to third item, app is crashing. Any help will be valuable for me. Thanks for helpings.

[image]

Here is my adapter code.

```
public class NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Communicator,Swappable{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ArrayList<NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem> myItems;



    public NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter(Context activity, ArrayList<NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem> listItemElements) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        myItems = listItemElements;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem getItem(int position) {
        return myItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return myItems.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem i = myItems.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_listview_simple, null);
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView123);
                holder.text.setText(i.textdata);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                parent.setTag(holder);
                holder.text.setTag(position);


        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String name) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String url, String type) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendMapValues(Geometry featureGeometry, Symbol featureSymbol, Object featureAttrValues) {
            //doinNothing
    }

    @Override
    public void swapItems(int i, int i2) {

        NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem obj1 = myItems.get(i);
        myItems.remove(i);
        myItems.add(i2,obj1);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since the app crashed, please show the logcat error messages. That will help us see the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code keeps adding the first item to the second position, but the second item gets removed. This happens internally in the ArrayList, not in the GUI.

I suggest a technique that just swaps the two items, basic swapping using a temporary object. This time the temp is obj1.
Sample code using your style:

```
public void swapItems(int i, int i2) {
   NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem obj1 = myItems.get(i);
   myItems.set(i, myItems.get(i2);
   myItems.set(i2, obj1);
}
```

Note: I am using the **ArrayList set** method instead of add().