# Why DynamicListview 's drag drop functionality works duplicated

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

i've been developing an android app so far. I want to add DynamicListview's drag-drop functionality to my ListView. I follow Google's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q) and use this tutorials code. I added successfully this functionality but drap drop works duplicately, when i touch the listview elements and drag it to another line , it creates another listview elements again. When i release my finger from listview element it works properly bu itself.Google's tutorial works properly too it has not got this issue. To clearify my problem i've added two video. First my video; [drag-drop issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twiHfLMdv7c&feature=youtu.be) and well-work [google's tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oIqVWVD3yg&feature=youtu.be) (As you see at the video when i try to move district, district field become duplicated at every move, google's tutorial works well)

How can i fix this issue.

My codes are long so i shared at github gist;

Here my DynamicListView Class;

https://gist.github.com/salihyalcin/bd9a3c23179f44212419

Here my NavigationDrawer Class:

https://gist.github.com/salihyalcin/620467a96fdce3129d1b

Lastly my NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter:

https://gist.github.com/salihyalcin/474423f5705dbe41e8d6

Comment: I have used this DynamicListView project and modified it to support 3 different columns in the Listview instead of just one. For just one column, the class DynamicListView works well. I'll post a possible solution for you some time later today when I get time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reviewed your code in DynamicListView and NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter class, mainly. As I said in my comments, I am familiar with the DynamicListView code and your code seems fine.

The problem that I see is that your `originalItem` stays visible in the original (wrong) position but internally the item (in the ArrayList object in NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter) is **no longer in the same position** in the ArrayList. This is a strong sign that the item is not being refreshed at the right time. You did call getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() in DynamicListView but that is good only for the 2 items being moved. The item not being moved, the original item, stays in the same wrong position but needs to be refreshed to be updated to the correct position. Visually I know this is not obvious!

I suspect the **getView** method in NavigationDrawerListViewAdapter needs the update. Method getView is responsible for displaying all the items in the Listiview! The code in getView has rather odd coding technique and needs to be coded in the conventional way, as suggested by Google developer.android.com. The good part is I think you don't need major code updates to fix your problem.

Code suggestion:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    final NavigationDrawerFragment.ListItem i = myItems.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_listview_simple, null);

        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView123);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(i.textdata);

    return convertView;
}
```

Notes:

1. The code `holder.text.setText` ensures that even the items that are not moving is refreshed like others.
2. For clarification, if `convertView` is not = null, it means the view is recycled and has been displayed in the current view. I think this is your issue.
3. I noticed the code using setTag method calls, and I skipped them because I don't see which code is referencing those tags anyway. Maybe you know better.

Comment: I dont know what to say for you, if I can upvote again and again, I would like to upvote your post for ever. You save my project. Really I'm so grateful to you. Thanks, thanks, and thanks again.

Comment: @salih, I m so happy for you! This is my goal in this blog community. The lucky thing is that I have used this project as I said.

Comment: @salih, Thank u for the kind words. Just for that, I'll check up on your next questions. I normally check on tag of "android-fragments" among few others.

Comment: Is there any possible communication way to communicate with you ? I really appreciate to you. Thank you.

Comment: @salih, I would rather see you post your questions and code in this SO blog community. If you like, you can send me email with the posted link. My email is listed on my profile.

Comment: @salih, There is a favor I can ask from you. I posted an answer from another question you posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791195/drag-drop-and-reorder-elements-in-listview . You did not respond to that one. If you think my post is useful, you may select as "useful" and as the best answer.  This year I m trying to spike up my rep points. Thanks.